# Can't open BIOS/UEFI, screen stays black

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I have an XMG Walker which I wanted to make a clean-install on.
The Win10 included reset did not work. I tried to boot from a bootable USB-Stick, which works on other devices(Media Creation Tool), but I could not go into the boot menu/UEFI/BIOS when pressing F2/F9/F10/F12/ENTER/DEL. 
So I launched the setup on the Stick from Windows itself. The installation started to process and at one point the Device tried to restart.

Ever since the screen stays black. When I press F2 at the startup, it seems to go to hibernate (according to the front-light that flashes slowly).

Any idea what might do the trick or what happened? I attached both: HDMI and Display Port to be sure to capture a signal when there is one. Also I once removed the SSD and still no image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reached out to XMG Walker company? I can't quickly find any manuals on its website, tech specs indicate it uses 'Intel HM170 Express' chipset, but it could be ANY BIOS/UEFI manufacturer. I believe its also possible they've locked you out of that, hopefully someone knows more than myself. Seems [you've posted in another forum](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&u=https://forum.worldofplayers.de/forum/threads/1533645-Komme-nicht-in-BIOS-UEFI&prev=search) where they had some good advice, notably to tell Windows to boot into UEFI. However it sounds like you're stuck being unable to get into Windows so that won't help. It really seems like you should reach out to the company about the black screen issue. Maybe in a separate request ask them about UEFI/BIOS access if you don't want them to think YOU caused the issue. However I speculate you won't be the last one to try & reinstall Windows fresh so I'd be curious how they plan to tackle these, especially with Windows 10 Feature Updates historically reinstalling the OS seemingly from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the XMG company. They told me that this behaviour is normal and that they are being delivered with a USB-Stick that allows to reinstall Windows (so no linux possible). After some talking they agreed to send me an additional USB-Stick. Anyway, I do not like the smell of this kind of hardware and decided to sell it..